# Do you agree GeoDirection should return 90 degrees in this example?

Tags: geodesy

```
GeoDirection[{38,-76},{38,-75}]
(* 89.6922 Degrees *)
```

I am using version 12.0.0.

Comment: Try ``GeoDirection[{38, -76}, {38, -76 + 0.001}]`` and ``GeoDirection[{38, -76}, {38, -76 + 180}]``. In the first case, the limit goes to ``90 Degrees``, and in the second case, it is ``0 Degrees``. Perhaps [this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G83q0.png) (!!) is of use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expected answer from `GeoDirection` will not be exactly 90 degrees for these inputs.

You are trying to find the direction between two points that lie on the same line of latitude.  And the 38<sup>th</sup> line of latitude does run due east from 38°N 76°W and intersects 38°N 75°W.

But `GeoDirection` finds the heading of a geodesic ("great circle") route between the two given points, and lines of latitude are not great circles on Earth's surface.  So there is a discrepancy between the line-of-latitude path and the great-circle path, explaining why the initial heading given by `GeoDirection` is a tiny bit north of east.

If I've done my spherical trigonometry correctly, then for two points at latitude $\lambda$ separated by a longitude $\Delta \phi$, the initial heading $\alpha$ between the two points will be given by
$$
\cot \alpha = \sin \lambda \tan \frac{\Delta \phi}{2}.
$$
Plugging in the numbers $\lambda = 38°$ and $\Delta \phi = 1°$ gives the same result as Mathematica.  We also see that:

- As $\Delta \phi \to 0$, the right-hand side goes to zero regardless of $\lambda$, and so $\alpha \to 90°$.  Thus, for small changes in longitude, the heading approaches due east.
- Similarly, for $\lambda = 0$, $\alpha = 90°$ regardless of $\Delta \phi$.  This is because the line of 0° latitude is the Equator, which *is* a great circle on the Earth's surface.

Comment: The default datum assumes an ellipsoidal earth. But if you assume a spherical earth then you get exactly the same angle calculated here. `In[24]:= 180/Pi*ArcCot[Sin[38 Degree] Tan[1 Degree/2]] - QuantityMagnitude[GeoDirection[GeoPosition[{38, -76}, "SphericalEarth"], GeoPosition[{38, -75}, "SphericalEarth"]]]

Out[24]= 0.`

Comment: @ChipHurst:  Yes, fair enough;  my calculation assumes a spherical Earth.